# Finding more than one result in a dataset in Delphi using locate

Tags: delphi, dataset, locate

I have a huge dataset of articles stating, among other details, their names, SKU numbers and vendors ID.

When I need to find an article, I use locate with a VarArrAyOf "SKU number" and "vendor ID", positioning the cursor on the wanted record and grabbing the rest of the info I need.

But I am facing a case where I can sometimes have to find an article based only on it's SKU number.
The dataset being open, my first though was to simply use the simple version of locate. But then I realized that some of my articles, sold by different vendors, sometimes have similar SKU numbers (some are just sequentially assigned). And if I am correct, locate (as would lookup) will stop searching after a match is found, ignoring further possible matches.

I thought about bookmarking the record that matched, moving the cursor one record further with next and launching a second search but, of course, locate starts from the beginning of the datasets and stops again at the same match...

I also did

```
          with DS_assets do
             begin
                DataSet.First;
                  while not DataSet.eof do
                    begin
                        //some comparison code
                      DataSet.Next;
                    end;
              end;
```

to loop through the entire dataset, one record after another untill eof, but this takes a long time and I think negates the advantage of the lookup function (or is it the way to go ?).

How would you deal with such a case ? Is there a "locate next" function available ? I am using Firedac by the way.

Thanks in advance and good day/nigh to all

Math

Comment: Which kind of dataset are you using? Is it connected to a SQL database? Please show the code that calls `Locate`. Or even better a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
 With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Comment: If your TDataSet.Locate criteria would match multiple records you're better off using the TDataSet.Filter property and then iterating through the filtered records.

Comment: Alternatively FireDAC has a LocateEx function which has options you can specify to search from the current position rather than the start of the dataset. Either way would work, but I'd probably go with the filter myself.

Comment: @LachlanG : thanks for the info. A while loop with locateEx did the trick for me. Thanks again for this addition to my arsenal :)